Modify source table column with specific conditions to make a new table in ADF dataflow
This is my requirement:
Make a existed source table to specific column transform to a new table in ADF.
Source Table Schema:
      Q090T varchar (2),
      Q0901 varchar(10),
      Q0955 varchar(2) NOT NULL,
      Q0906 varchar(6) NOT NULL

Sink Table Schema:
    ProductType varchar (10),
    ProductSubtype varchar(10),
    ProductNumber varchar(70) NOT NULL,
    ProductName varchar(60) 

the tansform rule are :

Set [ProductType] as 'Service' when [Q9055] column is '91' or
'92',
Otherwise, set [ProductType] as 'Other'
Set [ProductSubtype] as 'Product'
Mapping [ProductNumber] to [Q0906]   -- no transform
Set [ProductName] as 'ProductEnglishName'    (supposed to query
from other table, but fixed string is ok by now.)

so I sucked from the first 1) transform.
could you help to suggest to use which one in data flow?
I try to use derivedCloumn, but it seems not working as below.


Why can't you just handle the transformation logic in stored  proc?  Load the source data into staging table and then apply the transformation logic using stored proc and then load it into destination table. The 1st transform rule is simple case statement and the other one are straight forward.

You can use Rule-based mapping in the derived column of the Dataflow.
Use dataflow expressions for the values as per your required condition.
iif(Q0955=='91' || Q0955=='92','Service','Other')

These are the sample expressions in the derived column as per your given conditions. You can change these as per the column conditions.

After the derived column, delete the original columns from the source using select transformation and kept only the required target columns like below.

Then, add your target table as sink. If your table was already created, it will directly copy the data to it or else, you can make use Recreate table option in the sink settings.
Sample result:

